# Gradient view not displaying on simulator swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

so i added a gradient view to my UIView but when i run the app it doesn't display the UIVIEW properly please have a look at the screen shots i tried it running without the gradient and view worked perfectly[here you can see the code i wrote for gradient view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GPUM.png)

[and this is main story board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8VfZ.png)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, both of your gradient colors are white.

The cause why your gradient is not dispalying is you're specifying the locations wrong. There is no need to setup startPoint and endPoint so you can delete those lines.

```
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint.zero
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
```

And edit the locations to

```
gradient.locations = [0,1]
```

If you want to show the colors other way around, just switch them in the colors property.

Next time it would be useful to post the code regular way not as an screenshot.